# Start an Activity after sending to External URL

Tags: android

im trying to make a custom ad for a client, and he needs that when the user loads the app it shows the ad, he needs control of the img of the ad so i load it from an external url. 
The app starts with a SplashActivity that loads everytime the app starts, and after that i start the activity CustomAdActivity that has a Relative Layout with the ad. The thing is that when they click i send them to the ad this way:

```
 Intent viewIntent =
                        new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
                                Uri.parse("AD_URL"));
                startActivity(viewIntent);
```

And it works fine, but then i need to send the user to the MainActivity, and if just put below

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(CustomAdActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(mainIntent);
```

the app just straight sends the user to the main activity without opening the url,
i tried to put it in onPause, onStart and in onDestroy when i call finish(); after the url intent but it just doesn't work (with the last one just killing the app) i would love if someone helps me

Comment: When you exactly want to send the user to MainActivity ?

Comment: After the url is shown

Comment: I would recommend you ... to show url inside a webview ... search how to show website in webview and after that you get the callback based on that you can go for forwarding user to main activity

Comment: Isn't there another way? Because i tried your solution but the webview doesn't recognize certain urls that the ad redirects and fails

Comment: If you are sure that the ad will load and quickly say for 5 seconds it will show... Create a handler and just start that after 5 seconds...